# A question related to the completion of a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

This question is going to sound very trivial, but given a complete metric space $(X,d)$, how does one show that its completion *via* Cauchy sequences $(X^*,d^*)$ is itself?

I know that $X$ is dense in its completion $X^*$. So how can I make use of this fact to prove the above claim?

Any help/hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every cauchy sequence in a complete metric space can be identified with its limit.

Comment: The completion of a complete space is isometric to the space itself. If $X$ is complete, then any Cauchy sequence converges, so any two equivalent Cauchy sequences converge to a mutual limit and you can identify that limit with the equivalence class of equivalent Cauchy sequences. This identification is an isometry, so the completeness of $X^*$ follows directly from the completeness of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i:X \to X^*$ be the canonical inclusion. As stated in the comments $i$ is an isometry, in particular it is injective. $X$ is complete by assumption, so $\overline{i(X)}=i(X)=X^*$.
(Any element in the closure of $i(X)$ is a limit $i(x_n)_n$. Since $i$ is an isometry, the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $X$. Thus, converges.)
Thus, $i$ is bijective. One can show that $i$ is closed (not hard). Hence, $i$ is a homeomorphism.